# How to sum two vectors to obtain a matrix of sums of all pairs?

Tags: python, numpy

I want to sum all possible pairs taken from two vectors and to store the result as a numpy matrix or 2d array.

Two vectors:

```
v1 = np.array([1, 2, 3])
v2 = np.array([4, 5])
```

I need such result:

```
matrix([[5, 6],
        [6, 7],
        [7, 8]])
```

Is there an elegant way to do it with `numpy`?

Comment: Try : `v1[:,None]+v2`.

Comment: Thanks. Why does it work?

Comment: Google for `numpy broadcasting`.

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np

v1 = np.array([1, 2, 3])
v2 = np.array([4, 5])

m = np.column_stack((v1+v2[0], v1+v2[1]))
```

Output:

```
[[5 6]
 [6 7]
 [7 8]]
```

Comment: This answer only works if v2 only contain two values. Any other value need to be added manually.